# Emulate low resolution device on the chrome dev tool

Tags: android, angular, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, ionic3

I need to test the Ionic 3 app on a low-resolution device. But I don't have a low-resolution device.Can you tell me how to do that in the chrome dev tools?

Low-Resolution device: [**Zte**](https://www.mobileciti.com.au/zte-telstra-4gx-plus-grey?gclid=Cj0KCQjwgIPOBRDnARIsAHA1X3Rs9bT99-PYjF0qTddxkXdxi-oFagMNqyUm_m4EpypNtm0oyvwPVeoaAlzNEALw_wcB)

> Screen Size:  5.0 Inches, 480 x 854 pixels

[image]

Comment: You can use  remote debugg using chrome device inspect feature,

Comment: Yes, But I don't have a low-resolution device no. That is the issue here. That is why I need to simulate it on the browser.@rashidnk

Comment: You mean small screen device?

Comment: I need to simulate `Screen Size: 5.0 Inches, 480 x 854 pixels`.In other words resolution. @Duannx We cannot give pixels as it is since it is different than the `retina` screen's units.

Comment: I think it is hard to simulate `retina` in chrome dev tool. We only can change pixel of screen by clicking in `responsive` option or add an other device by clicking `edit`

Comment: Yes, But this won't work `480 x 854`. We need to convert it to device's unit. How to do that? @Duannx

Comment: I afraid of that chrome can not simulte `retina` if we give custom pixels. Choose device from exits list is the only way.

Comment: Again I'll have the same problem no? Which device should I choose to match the `Zte`? @Duannx :https://www.mobileciti.com.au/zte-telstra-4gx-plus-grey?gclid=Cj0KCQjwgIPOBRDnARIsAHA1X3Rs9bT99-PYjF0qTddxkXdxi-oFagMNqyUm_m4EpypNtm0oyvwPVeoaAlzNEALw_wcB

Comment: Since chrome device list does not have `Zte`, you have 2 choices now: 1. Edit the pixels. As i say above, you just simulated the `screen size` not the `retina`. So some style you set with `px` may not same as real device. 2. Give up with chrome dev tool and use some online test tool. That is all i can do in this situation

Comment: If I give the pixels then it won't work.You can see that the height is huge `854`. I strongly believe there must be a conversion of pixels to retina units and vice versa.Yes, this won't work perfectly like device. But at least we should find out a method to simulate it like default chrome dev tool devices.e.g. `Galaxy S5` has resolution `1920 x 1080`. But chrome dev tool gave it as `360x640` for us. So there must be a formula for that?
 @Duannx

Comment: The problem of online tool is I cannot debug it no? @Duannx

Comment: Galaxy S5 have `16:9` ratio so `640x360` is same as `1920x1080` in screen   size but  not the `retina`. What do you mean `won't work`? I tried editing the pixels and i recive the screen with the size i want. Online tools i know can not debug so we have to accept that no tool is perfect. We need make a choice.

Comment: I think we need that kind of ratio here too. Any idea how to do that?You can see that we cannot see the full page when I set up it. @Duannx https://i.imgur.com/beuNUlC.png

Comment: I have no idea about that. But it show 75% to fit your window. Just smaller but the ratio will not change

Comment: @Sampath we need pixel density of device or ppi which doesn't seem to be available and also not enough info to calculate. Then we can get logical pixel  resolution

Comment: Is this not enough? @SurajRao http://www.ztemobiles.com.au/A462.htm

Comment: Maybe https://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Blog/Pixel-Density-Pixels-Per-Inch-PPI-Explained/ba-p/9252950 will help .

Comment: Can't you construct an answer here? @SurajRao

Comment: @Sampath if I find the ppi i can.. otherwise as i said not enough info

Comment: Yes, It is there. Here it is : `Pixel Density (In PPI)
~ 196PPI`. See: https://www.pdevice.com/product/zte-blade-a462-price-specs @SurajRao

Comment: Ok.. that makes ~1.3 DPR.. will post answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the comments, the pixel density is `196PPI`.

The device pixel ratio  = `196/150=~1.3`

The logical resolution is screen size in `pixels/dpr` i.e. `(480x854)/1.3 = (369×657)` `width` and `height`.

Comment: What about `user agent string`? How can we find out that?

Comment: Check https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_platform/zte-android/&grqid=wqHLiSeL&hl=en-IN

Comment: Oh. Excellent. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Where did 150 come from?

Comment: @Darkguy it is the ideal pixel density. Check [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841812/how-to-calculate-device-pixel-ratio)