# How to take specific element screenshot in Selenium MOBILE webdriver?

Tags: selenium, image-processing, selenium-chromedriver, webpage-screenshot, mobileemulation

I am trying to take specific web element screenshot, but this method fails when Mobile mode is on in Chromedriver. Otherwise works perfectly in Desktop mode.

Mobile element screenshot is zoomed in as well as position is wrong (screenshot is cropped from first pixel and not from specified position `element.Position` (Which is not 0,0)

```
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementSelector));
            
            var byteArray = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
            var screenshot = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(byteArray));

            
            var croppedImage = new Rectangle(element.Location, element.Size);
            screenshot = screenshot.Clone(croppedImage, screenshot.PixelFormat);

            return screenshot;
        }
```

anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is to find mobile device pixel ratio and multiply Rectangle() parameters by it

[How to calculate device pixel ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841812/how-to-calculate-device-pixel-ratio/23958504)